# how to allow facebook bot access in protected hotlinking images

Tags: .htaccess, facebook-graph-api, hotlinking

I have already protected images for hotlinking, but I can't grant access to facebook bot. The configuration in my htaccess is:

```
#Prevent hotlinking
RewriteEngine on
#allows you to specify which files this applies to
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(?:js|css|gif|png|jpg)$
#if the client's (server's) IP address is not this
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http?://www\.my\.domains\.mx/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !="facebookexternalhit/1.1|facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)|Facebot"
# forbid access
#RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Well the probles is when I try to limit the user-agent to facebook, this doesn't work and the open graph api can get the images. Thanks!

Comment: if this is usesful for someone: RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit\/1\.1\ \(\+http:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/externalhit_uatext\.php\)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}`line to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(?:facebookexternalhit|Facebot) [NC]
```